# In Total War: Rome II, is it always viable to avoid capturing Israel/Jerusalem (if applicable)?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

I like the Total War series, and I was thinking about maybe getting Rome II sooner or later.  I also worship Jesus Christ, and I would be very surprised if Israel/Jerusalem is uncapturable in the game.  I know this is just a game, that none of it's supposed to have religious meaning in real life, it's supposed to be an amoral game, other Christians play it, etc.  It's just that I would still feel a little uneasy if the game somehow necessitated taking over an independent Israel under the Macabees.

(Contrast this from Empire: Total War, where the area is not only already held by a foreign empire, but it is not being used so much like a Jewish homeland.)

In Total War: Rome II, is it **always** viable to avoid capturing that one specific country/city, at least if it's independent on the game map?  If any of the campaigns or scenarios or whatever require you to take it over **during the game**, either practically or through the objectives list, the answer is no.  If it's required, but the country is not independent, then please specify.  Thanks!

Comment: What does Christianity have to do with Israel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 different victory types in *Total War: Rome 2*: Military, Economic, and Cultural.

Every victory type requires total control of 6 different provinces among other conditions. The provinces that need to be conquered depend on the faction you play as.

In the game, Jerusalem is a region of the province of Nabataea, and pretty much covers the entire territory of modern day Israel.

Of all the 12 factions, only [**Parthia**](http://guides.gamepressure.com/totalwarromeii/guide.asp?ID=22454) and [**Epirus**](http://guides.gamepressure.com/totalwarromeii/guide.asp?ID=22463) will need to conquer Nabataea — and with it, Jerusalem — for their Economic victory.

Since none of the victory types require any particular faction to be defeated, it doesn't matter if Jerusalem is independant or not.

---

#### TL;DR

No, unless you wish to achieve economic victory as Parthia or Epirus, or you're playing a campaign that specifically requires you to conquer Jerusalem, you will never have to conquer it.